# How to next image in scroll view  by next button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have image in scroll view it is loading images from the array i also want this that when i press nextbutton next image should appear I have done following code for loading images in scrollview i want to go prevoius and next image by button click  when i click next button it doesw not show next image

```
-(void) loadNews{

 NSURL*myurl=url; 

  myurl = [myurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
  myurl = [myurl stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet   whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 



  NSURL*urlloaded= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:myurl];
 //NSURL*url= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/RowOne.xml"];
  NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlloaded];

  //Initialize the delegate.

   RowTwoParser *parser = [[RowTwoParser alloc] initXMLParser];

  //Set delegate

   [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];   
   BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

  if(success)

   NSLog(@"No Errors");

   else

  NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");



  int k=0;
  for (int  i=0; i < [appDelegate.articles count]; i++) {



   CGRect frame;
   frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
   frame.origin.y = 0;
   frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
   UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
   RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:i];



   CGRect mywebframe=CGRectMake(20, 60, 728, 800);

   UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mywebframe];  


   NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;

   thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
   thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet   whitespaceCharacterSet]];



   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumb2];
   NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
   imageView.image =image2 ; 

   [subView addSubview:imageView];
   k++;
    }  

    //NSInteger numberofPages=10-j;
    NSInteger numberofPages=[appDelegate.articles count];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width *   numberofPages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
  CGRect frame;
  //frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
  frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * myindex;
  frame.origin.y = 0;
  frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
  [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];



  [pageControl setNumberOfPages:numberofPages];
  [pageControl setActivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [pageControl setInactivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  

   }
```

Next Button Code

```
   -(IBAction)nextButton{
     for (int nextIndex=[pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex < [appDelegate.articles count]; nextIndex++) {


   CGRect frame;
   frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * nextIndex;
   frame.origin.y = 0;
   frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
   UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];
   RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:nextIndex];



   CGRect mywebframe=CGRectMake(20, 60, 728, 800);

   UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mywebframe];  


   NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;

  thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
  thumb2 = [thumb2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet   whitespaceCharacterSet]];



   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumb2];
   NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
   imageView.image =image2 ; 

   [subView addSubview:imageView];
```

//  k+\
     }

```
  //NSInteger numberofPages=10-j;
  NSInteger numberofPages=[appDelegate.articles count];
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * numberofPages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
 CGRect frame;
 //frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
 frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * myindex;
 frame.origin.y = 0;
  frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
 [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];



  [pageControl setNumberOfPages:numberofPages];
  [pageControl setActivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [pageControl setInactivePageColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  


 }
```

Comment: You did not post what is happening now - I'm assuming it's failing, but is at compile time? Run time? What messages are you seeing?

Comment: now it shows all the images which are coming and can scroll them i want mean i have 3 images when load i should move to next image by button click

Comment: I have added next button code you can check now

Answer (score 0):

If they are in scroll view, you use

```
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(xPositionToScroll, yPositionToScroll);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

To some specific point.